# What is meant by a table header of the form $\rho\times10^{-4}\ (\Omega\cdot\rm m)$?

Tags: terminology, electrical-resistance, conventions, notation

I have read a question to calculate the resistance of a wire: its length is 10 meters, its cross-section area equals $0.1 \ \mathrm{cm}^2$, and its resistivity $\times10^{-4}$ is $0.05 \ \Omega \cdot \mathrm{m}$.

So what is meant by that?

> [image]

Comment: Do you know the general formula to determine the resistance of a wire of a certain length?

Comment: Anyway, I think that you can consider what you read as follows: you have not the resistivity $\rho$ of the material, but the resistivity multiplied by $10^{-4}$. That is: $\rho \cdot 10^{-4} = 0.05 \ \Omega$. So, by solving this equation, you have that the actual resistivity $\rho$ is $0.05 \cdot 10^{4} \ \Omega$.

Comment: Yes x means times

Comment: And not Ω but Ωm.

Comment: I have added an image of the of the question

Comment: This is a (admittedly confusing) way to indicate that the resistivity is given in unites of $10^{-4} \Omega m$. Then, $0.05 \times 10^{-4} \Omega m$ is (nowadays) more properly put as $5 \mu \Omega m$.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a question on terminology, not physics.

Comment: Why it is an off-topic question.?.i want to.know how to calculate the resistance

Comment: That's a poorly produced table.  The number 0.05 is probably meant to be the resistivity *times* $10^{+4}$.    I.e., the actual resistivity is $0.05\times 10^{-4}$.  @BowPark interprets this the same way, but a *wire* is assumed to be a conductor, and no wire has a resistivity of $0.05\times 10^{+4}$.  Do you know what the material is?  If not ... you have a conundrum.

Comment: How did you know?

Comment: The table reports $\rho_e$, which must then be multiplied by $10^{-4}$ as per heading.  This is quite common usage as there is no prefix for $10^{-4}$.  A clearer presentation would be to have $\rho_e$ and indicate that the units are $10^{-4}\Omega . m$ but the example of the OP  is quite common in technical (i.e. engineering) tabulations.

Comment: @JonCuster wat? I'm pretty sure there's a physics terminology tag around here somewhere.

Comment: @heather: the existence of a tag does *not* mean the question is on topic. See [this Meta post by Qmechanic](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4063/25301) for more details about when they are and are not on topic.

Comment: @KyleKanos Sure. That puts this one on the on-topic side the way I see it.

Answer (score 2):

The table is not (quite) reporting the resistivity $\rho_\mathrm{e}$; instead, it is reporting the 'auxiliary' quantity $10^{-4}\times\rho_\mathrm{e}$, in ohm-meters. As such, the first row in the table should be interpreted as saying that
$$
10^{-4}\times\rho_\mathrm{e} = 0.05 \: \Omega\:\mathrm{m},
$$
or, in other words, that
$$
\rho_\mathrm{e} = 0.05\times 10^{4}\: \Omega\:\mathrm{m}= 500\: \Omega\:\mathrm{m}.
$$
This is as far as the standard notation indicates one should read this.

---

**However**, as pointed out in the comments, this resistivity is *way* too high to correspond to a conducting material, if the reading is correct then you've got a reasonably good insulator on your hands. That is then strongly suggestive that the table is using nonstandard notation, and that you're meant to multiply by $10^{-4}$ instead of dividing, which would give you a resistivity of
$$
\rho_\mathrm{e} = 0.05\times 10^{-4}\: \Omega\:\mathrm{m}= 5\times 10^{-6}\: \Omega\:\mathrm{m},
$$
which is in line with e.g. a nichrome wire. Now, if that were the case, the standard notation would require the table heading to report $\rho_\mathrm{e}/10^{-4}\ (\Omega\: \mathrm{m})$ or  $\rho_\mathrm{e}\ (10^{-4}\:\Omega\: \mathrm{m})$ (though I would normally go for  $\rho_\mathrm{e}/(10^{-4} \:\Omega\: \mathrm{m})$ or similar notation).

The question then becomes, is your book using nonstandard notation? and here we can't tell without further context. The answer is one of the two I just gave, but you'll have to compare and contrast to the other parts of the context to figure out which one your book is using.

---

And, what can you learn from this? That using standard notation *does* matter.